# jQuery random positioning infinite loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to randomly position balloons within it's container without overlapping. Think I've got the positioning correct however an infinite loop is happening when I push the positions variable. I can't see where it's going wrong. The balloons are being dynamically added to the DOM via append() and have placed within a window load function, so it should work.

Code is:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    // Balloon positioning
    var containerW = 800;
    var containerH = 500;
    var positions = [];
    $('.balloony').each(function() {
        var coords = {
            w: $(this).outerWidth(true),
            h: $(this).outerHeight(true)
        };
        var success = false;
        while (!success)
        {
            coords.x = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerW-coords.w));
            coords.y = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerH-coords.h));
            var success = true;
            $.each(positions, function(){
                if (
                    coords.x <= (this.x + this.w) &&
                    (coords.x + coords.w) >= this.x &&
                    coords.y <= (this.y + this.h) &&
                    (coords.y + coords.h) >= this.y
                )
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            });
        }
        // positions.push(coords);
        $(this).css({
            top: coords.y + 'px',
            left: coords.x + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/g91rdq69/
(Enabling positions.push causes fiddle to crash)

Thanks!

Comment: One to check and one to prevent overlap, correct? console logs out Object {w: 120, h: 297, x: 50, y: 178}

Comment: Which line is the issue?

Comment: You are re var-ing success inside of the while loop.  Also, there are some weird errors on your fiddle.  One is just a copy-paste syntax issue but the other is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in here: Your balloony's don't fit the container

```
.balloony {
      background-color: red;
      width: 30px;/*110px;*/ /*here*/
      height: 70px;
      ...
```

I made minimal changes in JS as well.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Balloon positioning
        var containerW = 800;
        var containerH = 500;
        var positions = [];
        $('.balloony').each(function() {
            var coords = {
                w: $(this).outerWidth(true),
                h: $(this).outerHeight(true)
            };
            var success = false;
            while (!success)
            {
                coords.x = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerW-coords.w));
                coords.y = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerH-coords.h));
                var success = true;
                $.each(positions, function(){
                //console.log(this);
                    if (
                        coords.x <= (this.x + this.w) &&
                        (coords.x + coords.w) >= this.x &&
                        coords.y <= (this.y + this.h) &&
                        (coords.y + coords.h) >= this.y
                    )
                    {
                        success = false;
                        return false; //break .each if found
                    }
                });
            }
             positions.push(coords);
            $(this).css({
                top: coords.y + 'px',
                left: coords.x + 'px'
            });
        });
        });//added
```

Answer (score 1):

You have redefined variable **success** inside loop and hence changed its scope. So success with outer scope that will break loop is not changing resulting in infinite loop.

**Hence change var success = true; inside loop to success = true;**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    // Balloon positioning
    var containerW = 800;
    var containerH = 500;
    var positions = [];
    $('.balloony').each(function() {
        var coords = {
            w: $(this).outerWidth(true),
            h: $(this).outerHeight(true)
        };
        var success = false;
        while (!success)
        {
            coords.x = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerW-coords.w));
            coords.y = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerH-coords.h));
            success = true;
            $.each(positions, function(){
                if (
                    coords.x <= (this.x + this.w) &&
                    (coords.x + coords.w) >= this.x &&
                    coords.y <= (this.y + this.h) &&
                    (coords.y + coords.h) >= this.y
                )
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            });
        }
        // positions.push(coords);
        $(this).css({
            top: coords.y + 'px',
            left: coords.x + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's on the third line of the `while` loop. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: check this now, i am not changing/debugging the whole code as you will be in a best position to know what exactly you want to implement, but as per breaking loop is considered try the solution i have mentioned above.